# Reading Time Series from netCDF with python for a specific location and time is in seconds

Tags: python, csv, netcdf

I'm trying to extract a time series csv from a netcdf file.
I have a tried a few options and it seems that using xarray is the simplest one.

My variables I want are 'time' 'stage' and I want to specify the coords of 'x' and 'y'
Time happens to be in seconds, which messed me up when I tried the netCDF4 answers on this site.

I tried the following

```
import xarray as xr

 
ds = xr.open_dataset('boundary_conditions.sts') 
xi = 125285.25; yi = 42519.85  


dsloc = ds.sel(x=xi, y=yi, method='nearest')

dsloc['stage'].plot()
```

But I don't get past the 'dsloc' section as it says x is not defined.

Ideally I would also like to export it as a csv.

I'm sure it's an easy fix but I don't know what it is...

please help

This is the file if it helps

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dr3k7zynt54joti/boundary_conditions.sts?dl=0

Comment: x and y are variables, not coordinates or dimensions. You will need to convert them to coordinates. Alternatively you can just us `to_dataframe`, which is probably easier to work with

Answer (score -2):

Ideally, you would provide a reproducible example, but the following code should probably replace your final line:

```
dsloc.stage.plot()
```

Comment: I've added in the file link, and also the problem is when I try to use ds.loc, whatever I specify- x or time, it says it is not defined. I tried a few things but keep coming back to the same issue. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: In that case can you edit your post and remove the final line as anyone else will assume it is the final line that is failing